# How do I grant Azure Cloud Shell access to my Azure SQL Server using least-privilege?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Suppose I create an [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal) and want to use the [Azure Cloud Shell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/features/cloud-shell/) to administer it.

The first port of call would be the 'allow access to Azure services' option. However it is implied that this is rather too liberal as it allows access from *any* Azure service. I don't want to do that. I *only* want to grant access to the Cloud Shell.

The documentation describes setting up a server-level firewall rule - setting an IP address range of 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 would permit *any* IP to connect to the database. I don't want to do that either - this is clearly not production-ready and even more liberal than allowing access to any service within Azure.

I don't know the IP address of Cloud Shell, it's presumably dynamically allocated.

How do I grant access to **just** the Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell/CLI commands you execute in Azure Cloud Shell use the same management APIs as the Portal, so if you can manage a database in the portal than you can the exact same in Azure Cloud Shell. Firewall rules apply to data connections (i.e. T-SQL connections for running queries on the DB), not management operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your sql command via Cloud Shell an error will be returned that provide the IP address of Cloud Shell to be white listed in your azure SQL Server firewall! See sample commands and error below:

```
Import-Module SQLServer
Import-Module Az.Accounts -MinimumVersion 2.2.0
```

**Note**: the sample assumes that you or your DBA configured the server to accept connections using that Service Principal and has granted it access to the database (in this example at least the SELECT permission).

#### Obtain the Access Token: this will bring up the login dialog

```
Connect-AzAccount
$access_token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token

# Now that we have the token, we use it to connect to the database 'mydb' on server 'myserver'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver.database.windows.net -Database mydb -AccessToken $access_token`
              -query 'select * from Table1'
```

#### Database firewall

Network settings may block access.

--Invoke-Sqlcmd: Cannot open server 'myserver' requested by the login. Client with IP address '20.XXX.XXX.XX' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.